Изменение номенклаутры 1С
Всем привет! Возникает ошибка при попытке изменения номенклатуры с использованием протокола OData
Вот код:
def update(entity, guid, data, select=None, username=username, password=password):
    url = f'''http://localhost/mc/odata/standard.odata/{entity}(guid'{guid}')'''
    headers = dict(Accept='application/json')
    response = requests.patch(url, auth=(username, password), headers=headers, data=data)
    response.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
    json_response = response.json()
    return json_response

update(entity='Catalog_Номенклатура', guid='6831eb5d-4fc9-11ef-a320-000ec6c817c0', data={'Вес': 8}, username='Nick', password='')

Вот ошибка:
{'odata.error': {'code': '-1','message': {'lang': 'ru', 'value': 'Непредвиденный символ при чтении JSON'}}}


Помогло изменение запроса на:
update(entity='Catalog_Номенклатура', guid='6831eb5d-4fc9-11ef-a320-000ec6c817c0', data={'Вес': 8}, select = ["Вес"], username='Nick', password='')

